# График в Питоне в реальном времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Всем привет, хочу чтобы график с нуля перестраивался в реальном времени в одной и той же области. Нашел в интернете много примеров, которые у меня не сработали, график просто строится в новой области. Делаю все в JupyterNB (видимо в этом и причина).
Пример простых данных и мой код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'age': pd.Series([14, 18, 21, 30]),
     'weight': pd.Series([56, 75, 83, 72])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
new_weights_for_last = [75, 80, 100]

plt.ion()

for i in range(3):
    df.loc[3, 'weight'] = new_weights_for_last[i]
    plt.plot(df.age, df.weight)
    plt.draw() 
    plt.pause(3)

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анимационные графики строятся с помощью  функции  FuncAnimation из модуля анимации  matplotlib.animation,  которая позволяет автоматизировать обновление графика.

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html

А вот тут готовые примеры:
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96643/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation